# Show that the set of points equals the function

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $f : A \rightarrow B$ be a function and let $\text{graph}(f) := \{(x, f(x))\mid x \in A\}$.

Show that $\text{graph}(f)= f$.

Could you give me a hint for that? Isn't that obvious since $\{(x, f(x))\mid x \in A\}$ is also the definition of a function?

Comment: Yes, it’s obvious for precisely that reason.

Comment: That is not the definition of a function. Try starting from the actual definition of a function (as a set of pairs satisfying certain conditions that justify the use of the notation $f(x)$).

Comment: By definition of a function we have that $f(x)=\{(x,y) \mid x\in A, y\in B\}$. We have that $f(x)\in B$ therefore we have that $\text{graph}(f)\subseteq f$. For the other directionwe have to show that $y=f(x)$ for some $x\in A$,  or not? @RobArthan

Comment: Again that isn't the actual definition of a function. Start from the actual definition of a function as given in your notes or textbootk.

Comment: Which definition doyou mean? @RobArthan

Comment: I mean the definition that is given in your textbook or course material. It should say something like "a relation (or set of pairs) is called a function if ...".

Comment: A relation from a set $A$ to a set $B$ is called a function if each element of $A$ is related to exactly one element in $B$. So $f(x)=\{(x,y) : \forall x\in \  \exists ! y\in B \  : \  f(x)=y\}$, right? @RobArthan

Comment: @MaryStar - I would not define the core definition of a function using $f(x)$, as a function is a *set* that doesn’t depend on the point $x$. $f(x)$ is simply used to denote the unique $y$ such that $(x,y) \in f$; where $f := \{(x,y): x \in A, y \in B\}$.

Comment: So you mean to use the definition $f := \{(x,y): x \in A, y \in B\}$ and $\text{graph}(f)=\{(x,f(x))\mid x\in A\}$ ? Let $(x, y )\in f\Rightarrow x\in A \text{ and } y\in B$. We have that $f(x)\in B$ and so $f\subseteq \text{graph}(f)$. Let $(x,f(x))\in \text{graph}(f)$ with $x\in A$ and $f(x)$ is an element of the codomain, $f(x)\in B$ and so we get $\text{graph}(f)\subseteq f$. And so we get the equality of the sets. Is everything correct? @TaylorRendon

Comment: @MaryStar - yes. Also, as far as your work goes: looks good to me!

Comment: So is my proof complete? Or do we have to add something? @TaylorRendon

Comment: @MaryStar - Everything looks good to me as it is. You probably have already done this, but read the definition portion of this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_of_a_function. While this *Wikipedia*, with your proof you can see that indeed with the definition of a function it is equal to its graph, $G(f)$.